# Считать данные столбца с помощью pandas, зная лишь его буквенное обозначение

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel

Пытался воспользоваться кодом

```py
import pandas as pd

def read_excel_column(file_path, sheet_name, column_letter):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    column_index = pd.Index(df.columns).get_loc(column_letter)
    column_data = df.iloc[:, column_index].tolist()
    return column_data

file_path = 'путь_к_файлу.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'имя_листа'
column_letter = 'Z'
```

Но всегда возникает ошибка KeyError "Z".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно считать столбец аналогично:
`df["Название столбца"].tolist()`, зная лишь буквенное обозначение столбца "Z", без наименование столбца.

Comment: Колонки уже считаны через pd.read_excel. Но одну из колонок необходимо получить по буквенному обозначению, в отличие от остальных.

Comment: можно просто обратиться по числовому индексу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать параметр `usecols`, описанный в [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```py
def read_excel_column(file_path, sheet_name, column_letter):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, usecols=column_letter)
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
```

Так у вас будет прочитана только нужная колонка, она будет единственной в датафрейме.

Если же вы хотите не ограничиваться чтением из экселя одной колонки, то, полагаю, будет работать такой подход, основанный на порядковом номере буквы, обозначающей колонку:

```
import string

def col2num(col):
    num = 0
    for c in col:
        if c in string.ascii_letters:
            num = num * 26 + (ord(c.upper()) - ord('A')) + 1
    return num

column_data = df.iloc[:, col2num(column_letter) - 1].tolist()
```

Использована функция из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12640614/8324991).

Comment: Так как у меня очень большой объём данных и считываю я далеко не 1 колонку, хотелось бы оставить прежние колонки и не переоткрывать pd.read_excel, а сразу спарсить столбец через буквенное обозначение, если это возможно.

Comment: @Эникейщик полностью с вами согласен, это следовало уточнить изначально

Comment: @AndrewPower Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос (именно дополнить, а не переписать, исходную формулировку лучше оставить, а уточнение написать внизу вопроса). А я уже дополнил ответ.